# how to solve Unable to find help for https- while trying to push to gitHUb

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

```
git init
git status
git add .
git status
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/baweezy02/demography.git
git push -u origin master
```

I tried to change the gitHub remote repo

git remote set-url demography https://github.com/baweezy02/demography.git

Now: fatal: No such remote 'demography'

Comment: "git remote add **origin**" but "git remote set-url **demography**"

Comment: ^ What they said. `git remote set-url` only works on existing remotes, and `demography` is not an existing remote (but `origin` is).